# My site is hacked, error MYSQL Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My website and every other website i hosted with one hosting service was hacked yesterday. Other site from other host is still intact. I was logged on when it happened, so I was able to recover my site but, the phpMyAdmin has been tampered with. I created a new database after the old one failed to connect, created a new user for it, and granted all privileges. But when I enter the phpmyadmin page, I run the following queries;

```
 SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

RESULT;
USER()
CURRENT_USER()
cpaneluserid@localhost
cpaneluserid@localhost

```
 SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user;
```

RESULT;

## 1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'cpaneluserid'@'localhost' for table 'user'

```
 SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='' AND host='localhost';
```

RESULT;

## 1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'cpaneluserid'@'localhost' for table 'user'

Well this clearly shows that another user, which is the cpanel username is having access to the database instead of the one I set privilege for.

This is my connection file;

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
session_start();

$dbserver = "localhost";
$dbroot = "user";
$dbpwd = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "dbname";
$link = mysqli_connect("$dbserver", "$dbroot", "$dbpwd","$dbname"); 

if(mysqli_connect_errno($link))
{
echo 'Failed to connect to database: '.mysqli_connect_error();
}else { }
```

When I open a page that contains that file, it shows;
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Please I need to resolve this quickly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you change username and password?

Comment: How do you mean? I've changed the username and password before for the old database and then I created the new one, let me change it again and see.

Comment: I just did, but same results.

Comment: What do you mean? You don't have an access to your Database now? even in Manual process?

Comment: Yeah. Am surprised too.

Answer (score 0):

The user have not permission or proper Privilege, Please provide full access to that user.

Comment: I did already, checked ALL PRIVILEGES  and am actually lost on what next to do. Not very good with MySQL.